# How to do an old style animated counter that increases and decreases in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, counter, odometer

I'm trying to do an **animated old style odometer counter** and found a package [odometer](https://pub.dev/packages/odometer) which works perfectly but the problem is that it only accepts and displays **int values** in the UI and I need to display **double values**, does anyone have any idea if this is possible or should I just make one myself?

PS: The code I have is the one that is in the **package example page**.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

Comment: How about this one ? https://pub.dev/packages/animated_flip_counter

Comment: I will give it a try thxn :D

Answer (score 1):

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVQP.png)

```
return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
                // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
                title: Text('NiiTii'),
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>\[
                    Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: AnimatedSlideOdometerNumber(
                        letterWidth: 20,
                        odometerNumber: OdometerNumber(_counter),
                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                        numberTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple,width: 15.0),
        
                        color: Colors.red
                      ),
                    ),
                       Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                      child: SlideOdometerTransition(
                        letterWidth: 20,
                        numberTextStyle:  TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
        
                  ],
                ),
              )
        
            );
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what does this piece of code exactly?

Comment: I had added decoration on AnimatedSlideOdometerNumber(). U can use exactly to retrieve the same output.